# Show that f(x) defined on [0,infinity) R to is continuous at 0.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &:& x=0\\[1ex]x^{\frac{2}{3}} \log x&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

My thoughts: $\log x$ behaves weird in $(0;1)$ and will not be bounded for any $ x \in V_{\delta} (0) , \delta >0 $

Now is $ x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ small enough to keep $\log x$ in control? How can I show this? Please help. I'm looking for a proof using the definition of continuity.

Comment: You can get MathJax typesetting by placing the math inside single `$` (for inline math) or double `$$`. `[math]` does not work here.

Comment: Ok I think it's better now. Edits are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $x^{\frac{2}{3}}\log x = \dfrac{\log x}{x^{-\frac{2}{3}}}$, and proceed to use L'hospitale rule to find the limit as $x \to 0^{+}$.

Comment: I can do it this way. However, I want a proof using the definition of continuity, if possible, since we've not yet covered L'Hopitals rule in my undergrad class.

Comment: @kiyokiTio $x^{2/3}\log x$ is the product of two functions both continuous in $(0;\infty)$.  The issue then is what happens at the limit down to zero.  You need some technique to show $\lim\limits_{x\searrow 0} x^{2/3}\log x=0$.

Comment: Yes. But we're only concerned with checking continuity at 0. So I cannot do this using the epsilon delta definition?

Comment: Par reply, graham kemp sir.

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic fact of calculus that
$$\lim_{x\to0+}x^\alpha\>\log x=0\qquad(\alpha>0)\ .\tag{1}$$
This immediately shows that your function is continuous at $0$.

There are various ways to prove $(1)$, depending on your toolbox. If you don't want to use Hôpital's rule you have to resort to
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}{e^t\over t}=\infty$$
or similar. The most basic fact in this regard is $2^n>n$, which can be proven using Cantor's diagonal principle: The set $\{1,2,\ldots,2^n\}$ contains the $n+1$ numbers $1$, $2$, $\ldots$, $2^n$.